React Router redirecting to login page with AuthContext
I am having trouble understanding why my protected route in react (using react-router) is always redirecting to login page after I login.
I have a node js server that has endpoints for logging in and logging out which generate a JWT. I am also generating a refresh token which is stored in http-only cookie.
The token is being sent in the response when user logs in and I am trying to store this in a react-app state with AuthContext. (not local storage)
I have a protected route component that checks if there is a token in the state. If not redirect user to login page otherwise render children.
From my console.logs it seems that the protected route is always getting empty token (undefined) even after I login.
I tried logging the response from server after logging in and it shows the token in sent back successfully however i think the protected route is ran first before the call
i am using axios to make my api calls from react and I have interceptors in my AuthProvider.jsx code that send the token in the header on each call the application made
I also have an interceptor on the response to check if we got an error which calls my /refreshToken endpoint on my server to refresh the token.
I am new to react so any suggestions is appreciated!
// ProtectedRoute.jsx
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthProvider';
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {

  const { token } = useAuth();
  console.log('token in state ', token);

  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

// Login.jsx
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthProvider';
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login } = useAuth();

  const handleLogin = (values) => {
    login(values);
    navigate('/homepage');
  };

return <>...form </>

// App.jsx
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Registration />} />
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
              <Route element={<Homepage />} path="/homepage" />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

// AuthProvider.jsx
const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!authContext) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within a AuthProvier');
  }

  return authContext;
};

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [token, setToken] = useState(null); // empty state means undefined
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // this gets called one time when app launches to determine if user is logged in or not.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await client.get('/me');
        const availableToken =
          response.config.headers.Authorization.split(' ')[1];
        if (availableToken) {
          setToken(availableToken);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setToken(null); // we tried to fetch api and theres no token
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  const login = async (user) => {
    await client
      .post('/login', user)
      .then((response) => {
        const token = response.data.token;

        setToken(token);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  const ctxValue = {
    token: token,
    setToken: setToken,
    login: login
  };


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>{ !loading && children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

My initial implementation is dervied from the following tutorial i found helpful on youtube that explained JWT and Auth in React Authentication In React

The token state is initially null which matches your "unauthenticated" state and the user is redirected to the login page. Use an initial token that neither indicates "authenticated" nor "unauthenticated", e.g. undefined, and wait for the effect to run to confirm user authentication, e.g. a user object or null, then render the Outlet or redirect.

I don't quite get you, im initially setting it to null as your suggestion, I'm confused on why it's always redirecting back to the login page after the user logs in, which indicates the protected route is running before the login function that's actually calling the api

I suggested not initializing token to null since this matches your unauthenticated user state. I suggested using undefined as the initial value, and only redirect when it's set to null. It redirects because the initial token value is falsey and you don't differentiate between null being "unauthenticated" and null being "don't know yet". Does this difference make sense?

Yes i see what you're saying. I have adjusted my code to have token as undefined (initial state) and I am checking for undefined state in my protectedRoute and I'm showing a loading message..
however the behaviour is the same.

See if you can create a running Codesandbox demo of this code that reproduces the issue that we could take a look at live. Please mock the client.get('/me') function response/return value.

I've created a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/epic-antonelli-r6p8cv let me know if you can access it.
This is what I'm facing atm in my env, when I login first time , it doesn't redirect, however second time it does. ( sam thing on sandbox )

In your Login component code in the handleLogin handler it appears you call login from the AuthContext and then immediately call navigate("/"). This will obviously fail as the login hasn't completed yet and so no token is set. The login handler in AuthProvider should return a Promise, e.g. return mockApiCall(....) such that handleLogin can await login(values); then call navigate("/");. Making these changes in your sandbox makes the login flow function as I believe you are expecting.

Yes I spotted that late yesterday evening and that fixed my issue! I did however lose the ‘loading’ ability ( I don’t see the loading page anymore ) I did try to throttle network call but same thing. At least main problem is fixed!

FWIW I don't see any "loading page" code in your sandbox. The UI is just blank while the useEffect hook in AuthProvider calls mockApiCallMe and its 3 second timeout is running. Either way, happy to have helped. Cheers.
